# Access header values with [] in net/http

Tags: ruby, http

I want to make HTTP header requests in Ruby. For that I am using the following code

```
Net::HTTP.start(target) do |http|
  http.open_timeout = 2
  http.read_timeout = 2
  http.head('/').each do |k, v|
    puts "#{k}: #{v}"
  end
```

So far so good, but I would like to access the values of http.head rather in a Hash like fashion:

```
 header = http.head('/')
 p header['Content-Type']
```

Browsing through the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3//libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPFound.html) I started wondering why `each` is a method in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually works:

```
http_response = nil
Net::HTTP.start("stackoverflow.com", 80) do |http|
  http_response = http.head("/")
end

http_response['cache-control'] -> "public, max-age=10"
```

see: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-head

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there is an appropriate method in the Ruby `net/http` library, but from your code you could always create your own `Hash` with the following snippet:

```
headers = Hash.new
http.head('/').each { |k, v| headers[k] = v }
puts header['Content-Type']
```

After all library methods should only provide a basic function and the rest has to be done by your application. Although I am very curious if this really is not possible in another way.